# MySql, How to select data by comparing 2 Jsons

Tags: mysql, json

I have a json data like this

```
{"0":"6","1":"5","2":"10"}
```

And on the DB I have table which contains json datas like these

```
{"0":"6","1":"4"}
{"0":"5","1":"2","2":"7"}
{"0":"3","1":"10","2":"4"}
{"0":"6","1":"5","2":"10","3":"8"}
```

So, I would like know is it possible or does it make sense to select data by comparing the json datas?

I would like to get any json that may contain any `key:value` in my input json.
So, from my example they will be these

```
{"0":"6","1":"4"}
{"0":"6","1":"5","2":"10","3":"8"}
```

Comment: so , do you need any json data which contain the full provided json ? or want any json that may contain any `key:value` in your input json ? and please provide more details about your data table engine and mysql version , that would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON search functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html). For example -

```
SELECT json_field FROM table1
WHERE
  JSON_CONTAINS(json_field, '{"0":"6"}')
  AND JSON_CONTAINS(json_field, '{"1":"5"}')
  AND JSON_CONTAINS(json_field, '{"2":"10"}');
```

Comment: why not using full text search instead ? and is there a way to dynamically search for the full json ? for example , without providing the chunky json ?

Comment: It is a solution, json-functions are used for JSON data. Fulltext..., maybe it is also possible.